# How to get only the value from the database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

---

When i print I get the result like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [subscription_email] => example@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [subscription_email] => test@gmail.com ) )
```

but i want to get it like

```
example@gmail.com, test@gmail.com
```

Here is my code for the result

```
$data['subscribers'] = $this->Admin_model->getSubscribers();
$to_email = $data['subscribers'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply loop through your array and add each value to a variable. Either an array or a string:

```
<?php
    $dataset = $this->Admin_model->getSubscribers();
    $outputArray = [];

    foreach($dataset as $row) {
       $outputArray[] = $row['subscription_email'];
    }
    // in case you wish for an array
    $to_email = $outputArray;
    // in case you need a comma separated string:
    $to_email = implode(',', $outputArray); 
?>
```